# ruby on rails marketplace and stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am building a two side marketplace with RoR, 
and i want to use stripe to handle the payment.

I want the user to do a request and pay, (but using capture false, to charge later), and charge (or cancel) when the user providing the service accept or deny the request.

So what i've done so far:

.Submiting the request
.creating a new request in the DB (with a boolean statut)
.User can valid or not

But now i don't know how to record the outcome and update the statut of this request and so that point make a new api call to update the payment.

Anyone already done that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'd [create the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) with `capture` set to `false`:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  destination: 'acct_...',
  application_fee: 200,
  capture: false,
})
```

If the charge succeeds, you'd save the charge's ID (`charge.id`) in your database.

Then, if the transaction is confirmed, you'd [capture the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge) like this:

```
# Retrieve charge_id from your database
charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(charge_id)
charge.capture
```

If the transaction is canceled, you'd release the authorization by [refunding the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_refund):

```
# Retrieve charge_id from your database
refund = Stripe::Refund.create({
  charge: charge_id,
})
```

Note that uncaptured charges are [automatically released after 7 days](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture).

In the above, I assumed you were creating charges [through the platform](https://support.stripe.com/questions/does-stripe-support-authorize-and-capture), i.e. with the `destination` parameter. If you are instead charging [directly on connected accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-directly), you'd need to modify the requests to use the [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header:

```
# Create the charge directly on the connected account
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
  amount: 1000,
  currency: 'usd',
  application_fee: 200,
  capture: false,
}, {stripe_account: 'acct_...'})
# Save charge.id in your database

# Capture the charge
charge = Stripe::Charge.retrieve(charge_id, {stripe_account: 'acct_...'})
charge.capture

# Release the uncaptured charge
refund = Stripe::Refund.create({
  charge: charge_id,
}, {stripe_account: 'acct_...'})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting info on refund process. It worked for me too.